# Como ocultar colunas de tabela caso não existam registro no banco de dados?

Tags: php, mysql, while

```
<?php 
    // Pega o id do produto vindo da URL
    $id_produto = $_GET['produto'];
?>

<table width="100%" class="table table-bordered table-inverse table-hover table-responsive text-uppercase" id="tb_dados_produtos">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">CÓD/FABRICAÇÃO</th>
    <th scope="col">Tamanho</th>
    <th scope="col">Peso</th>
    <th scope="col">Unidades</th>
    <th scope="col">Cor</th>
    <th scope="col">Nº</th>
    <th scope="col">Matérias</th>
    <th scope="col">Folhas</th>
  </tr>
<?php if(isset($id_produto)) { $D = $Exibir->VerDados($id_produto); if(is_array($D)) { foreach($D as $d) { // Repetir linha conforme registros do BD ?>   
  <tr>
   <?php if(!empty ($d['Codigo_Fabricacao'])){ // Se não estiver vasio exiba os dados ?>
    <td align="center"> <?php echo utf($d['Codigo_Fabricacao']);  ?> </td>
    <?php }else{ // Se estiver vasio não exibir?>
    <td align="center" scope="row">-</td>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php if(!empty ($d['Tamanho'])){ ?>
    <td align="center"><?php echo utf($d['Tamanho']);  ?></td>
    <?php }else{ ?>
    <td align="center" scope="row">-</td>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php if(!empty ($d['Peso'])){ ?>
    <td align="center"><?php echo utf($d['Peso']);  ?></td>
    <?php }else{ ?>
    <td align="center" scope="row">-</td>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php if(!empty ($d['Unidades'])){ ?>
    <td align="center"><?php echo utf($d['Unidades']);  ?></td>
    <?php }else{ ?>
    <td align="center" scope="row">-</td>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php if(!empty ($d['Cor'])){ ?>
    <td width="385" align="center"><?php echo utf($d['Cor']);  ?></td>
    <?php }else{ ?>
    <th width="40" align="center" scope="row">-</th>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php if(!empty ($d['Numero'])){ ?>
    <td width="98" align="center"><?php echo utf($d['Numero']);  ?></td>
    <?php }else{ ?>
    <th width="40" align="center" scope="row">-</th>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php if(!empty ($d['Materias'])){ ?>
    <td width="98" align="center"><?php echo utf($d['Materias']);  ?></td>
    <?php }else{ ?>
    <th width="40" align="center" scope="row">-</th>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php if(!empty ($d['Folhas'])){ ?>
    <td width="98" align="center"><?php echo utf($d['Folhas']);  ?></td>
    <?php }else{ ?>
    <th width="44" align="center" scope="row">-</th>
    <?php } ?>

  </tr>
<?php } } } // Fecha While de repetição ?>  
<?php  if(empty ($d['Codigo_Fabricacao'])){ // Se não existir código de fabricação exiba linha de erro. ?> 
  <tr>
    <td colspan="8" align="center"><span class="text-center text-danger"><strong>Desculpe mas não existe informações para esse produto !!! </strong></span></td>
  </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Cuidado com a função `empty()`, por ex, se alguns dos valores forem "0", deves querer mostrar, no entanto não vai mostrar porque `empty(0) == true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**@EDIT**

```
<?php 
    // Pega o id do produto vindo da URL
    $id_produto = $_GET['produto'];
?>
<?php if(isset($id_produto)) { $D = $Exibir->VerDados($id_produto); if(is_array($D)) { foreach($D as $d) { // Repetir linha conforme registros do BD ?>
    <table width="100%" class="table table-bordered table-inverse table-hover table-responsive text-uppercase" id="tb_dados_produtos">
        <tr>
            <th style="<?php if (empty ($d['Tamanho'])) { echo 'display: none;';} ?>" scope="col">Tamanho</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <?php if(!empty ($d['Tamanho'])){ ?>
                <td align="center"><?php echo utf($d['Tamanho']);  ?></td>
            <?php }else{ ?>
                <td align="center" style="display: none;"></td>
            <?php } ?>
        </tr>
    </table>
<?php } } } // Fecha While de repetição ?>  
<?php  if(empty ($d['Codigo_Fabricacao'])){ // Se não existir código de fabricação exiba linha de erro. ?> 
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="8" align="center"><span class="text-center text-danger"><strong>Desculpe mas não existe informações para esse produto !!! </strong></span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<?php } ?>
```

Como você pode ver no código:

```
se (o tamanho retornar vazio) faça
    adicionar style="display: none;" ao elemento th
fim
```

O mesmo para o elemento td

Comment: To ligado nisso porém no cabeçalho dela tem como fazer algum esquema antes do while que repete as linhas ?

Comment: Você ta querendo fazer o <th> sumir também caso não tenha valores naquela coluna? É isso?

Comment: Exatamente mano.

Comment: Eu editei o código.

Comment: (Y) Vlew irei verificar.

Comment: Se possível dizer se funcionou  ou não.

Comment: Olá amigo, então eu consegui pondo o cabeçalho da tabela no fim dela ao consigo fazer funcionar. Seu código funciona mas não é possível repetir caso tenha mais dados nessa tabela. Mas vlew pela dica.

Comment: Por nada, se puder postar o código que funcionou corretamente, poderia ajudar pessoas com a mesma dúvida no futuro.